# How do I implement this class expression in Java OWLAPI?

Tags: java, ontology, owl

This is an example of a class expression for use in a
demo application:

```
Lecturer
and (hasResearch some (relatedTo some Semantic_Web))
and (teaches at-least 3 Course)
and (hasTitle value "Assist.Prof.")
```

And I create OWLAPI objects via these methods (create OWL object from String).

```
 OWLClass lecturer = m.createOWLClassFromString("Lecturer");
 OWLObjectProperty hasResearch = m.createOWLObjectPropertyFromString("hasResearch");
 OWLObjectProperty teaches = m.createOWLObjectPropertyFromString("teaches");
 OWLNamedIndividual sWeb = m.createOWLNamedIndividualFromString("Semantic_Web");
 OWLClass course = m.createOWLClassFromString("Course");
 OWLDataProperty hasTitle = m.createOWLDataPropertyFromString("hasTitle");
```

How do I implement that class expression on Java ?

[edit #1]
I got the implementation:

```
OWLClass lecturer = m.createOWLClassFromString("Lecturer");
        OWLObjectProperty hasResearch = m.createOWLObjectPropertyFromString("hasResearch");
        OWLObjectProperty isRelatedToResearch = m.createOWLObjectPropertyFromString("isRelatedToResearch");
        OWLObjectProperty teaches = m.createOWLObjectPropertyFromString("teaches");
        OWLNamedIndividual sWeb = m.createOWLIndividualFromString("Semantic_Web");
        OWLClass course = m.createOWLClassFromString("Course");
        OWLClass researchArea = m.createOWLClassFromString("ResearchArea");
        OWLDataProperty hasTitle = m.createOWLDataPropertyFromString("hasTitle");
        OWLDatatype dt = m.getDataFactory().getRDFPlainLiteral();
        OWLLiteral asstprof = m.getDataFactory().getOWLLiteral("Asst. Prof. Dr.",dt);

        OWLClassExpression relateToSomeResearchArea = df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(isRelatedToResearch, researchArea);
        OWLClassExpression hasResearchRelateToSomeResearchArea = df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(hasResearch,relateToSomeResearchArea);
        OWLClassExpression teachesAtLeastThreeCourse = df.getOWLObjectMinCardinality(3, teaches, course);
        OWLClassExpression hasTitleAsstProf = df.getOWLDataHasValue(hasTitle, asstprof);

        Set s1 = new HashSet();
        s1.add(lecturer);
        s1.add(hasResearchRelateToSomeResearchArea);
        s1.add(teachesAtLeastThreeCourse);
        s1.add(hasTitleAsstProf);

        OWLObjectIntersectionOf iof = df.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(s1);

        System.out.println(iof.getNestedClassExpressions());
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to happen here? You want some more Java to go along with your declarations that will draw those links and output OWL?

Comment: Thanks,dude. But i've got it on my own. See edit.

Comment: @KorrIamnot Glad to hear you got this figured out.  Would you post your solution as an answer and accept it? It will make everything clearer, and to reduce the number of unanswered questions, too.